# generate original files from webpack bundle

Tags: webpack, deobfuscation

I'm trying to generate source files from a webpack bundled js file. I have the sourcemap as well. I can see them in the chrome source tab, but I'm trying to save them locally.
Is there a ways to generate the original files, just like how chrome dev tool does in the source tab?